# How to use this function AddToArray?

Tags: c, function

I took from here http://fydo.net/gamedev/dynamic-arrays  the quality of the dynamic array.
But I do not know how to use it and I get this error:

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:26:25: warning: comparison between pointer and     integer [enabled by default]
test.c:35:39: error: expected expression before 'DATA'
test.c: In function 'AddToArray':
test.c:72:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'realloc' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
test.c:72:30: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'realloc' [enabled by default]
```

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", AddToArray(DATA 5));
```

I read the tutorial and know the syntax of the language, but for some reason they did not teach me that. So tell me how to use this function correctly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's an example of how to use the function on the page you linked to:

> I’ve got a little example available right here:
>
> Download Example – (arrays.c – 2kb)

I'd suggest you start with that and modify the code until you understand it and can use it for whatever it is you are intending to do.

Comment: DATA temp;
       temp.arg = malloc((strlen(argv[i]) + 1) * sizeof(char));
       strncpy(temp.arg, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
       if(AddToArray(temp) == -1) //если возникли проблемы с памятью
             return 1;

Comment: Now everything works!

Answer (score 0):

What you have is syntactically incorrect.  The `AddToArray` function expects to be passed a variable of type `DATA`.  What you're doing is passing the name of the type followed by whitespace followed by an integer constant, which is invalid.

Declare a variable of type `DATA`, populate the fields, then pass that variable to `AddToArray`.

Also, the compiler is complaining that there is no declaration for `realloc`.  You need to `#include <stdlib.h>` to get it.

Comment: *the_array->"Mike";
          *the_array++;
          *the_array->5;
           fprintf(stdout, "%d\n",     AddToArray(the_array));

Comment: I forgot how to assign them a value through a pointer.

Comment: Still on the Internet And I can not remember in any way